# Include and compile C++ header file from C

Tags: c++, c

I have a C++ file and its header file. I need to include this header file in a C code and use the functions in it.

When the `cpp.h` file is compiled through `main.c`, compilation fails because of the C++ linkage.

On using the macro `__cplusplus` `stream` and `string` are not resolved, is there some way to compile the `cpp.h` file through and execute?

I have given a outline of my code only.

C++ header file `cpp.h`:

```
struct s1
{
string a;
string b;
};
typedef struct s1 s2;
class c1
{
public:
void fun1(s2 &s3);
private: 
fun2(std::string &x,const char *y);
};
```

C++ file `cpp.cpp`:

```
c1::fun1(s2 &s3)
{
 fstream file;

}

c1::fun2(std::string &x,const char *y)
{

}
```

C file `main.c`:

```
#include "cpp.h"
void main()
{
 c1 c2;
 s1 structobj;
 c2.fun1(&structobj);
 printf("\n value of a in struct %s",structobj.a);

}
```

Comment: You can't use C++ classes (and many other things) in C.

Comment: Can you compile `main.c` using the C++ compiler instead?

Comment: No... there is no possibility of compiling main.c using c++ compiler because of dependency

Comment: Does call back solves this problem ? By introducing another cpp file to handle call back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by introducing a wrapper to c++ function. The C function calls the wrapper function which inturn calls the desired C++ function (including member functions).
More details are available [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp)

Answer (score 8):

Basically, you can't.
You need to put only C functions in your header file.
You put them in a `extern "C"` block this way:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

extern void myCppFunction(int n);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The `extern "C"` block is not recognized by a C compiler, but the C++ compiler need it to understand he have to consider functions inside as C functions.

In your cpp file you can define `myCppFunction()` so that she uses any C++ code, you will get a function C code can use.

Edit: I add a full example of how to link a program with a C `main()` using some C++ functions in a module.

stackoverflow.c:

```
#include "outputFromCpp.h"

int main()
{
    myCppFunction(2000);

    return 0;
}
```

outputFromCpp.h:

```
#ifndef OUTPUT_FROM_CPP_H
#define OUTPUT_FROM_CPP_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

extern void myCppFunction(int n);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

outputFromCpp.cpp:

```
#include "outputFromCpp.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void myCppFunction(int n)
{
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Compiling and linking:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -c stackoverflow.c
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++98 -c outputFromCpp.cpp
g++ -o stackoverflow.exe stackoverflow.o outputFromCpp.o -static
```

You cannot link such a program with gcc.
If you want to link with gcc you need to put all the C++ code in a shared library, I don't put an example as it would be a bit platform dependent.

Comment: If your program includes any C++ code or libraries, link with the C++ compiler.  It's also sensible to make the `main()` program into C++ code, even if it is written as: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { return real_main(argc, argv); }` (or, if the code ignores command line arguments, then `int main() { return real_main(); }`) where, in each case, `real_main()` is the C function that would be `main()` if you weren't using a minimal C++ `main()` instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The toolchain is providing a wrapper main for you anyway, that knows about C++ globals initialization.

Comment: Is that possible to include a callback by introducing another c++ file. where the new cpp file uses the function to extract value and using call back from c file to the new c++ file.

Comment: @user4402433 I am not sure I understand your question. In my example I can put any C++ code in `myCppFunction()`, including creating C++ objects with `new` and deleting them with `delete`, or calling code from another C++ module. Does that answer your question?